# object value is showing using JSON parsing for object and string with same name

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below not going inside of the JSON object block and does not returning anything .in the below response if the value is a JSON object it should return the value .if is not object it should go to else block and returning the string.

can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

response:

```
{
  "name": "account_id",
  "value": {
      "value": "11x52925",
      "label": "VS Hospital"
  },
  "label": "Account Name",
  "uitype": "51",
  "type": {
      "defaultValue": null
  }
},
```

accounts.java:

```
if (name.equals("account_id")) {
   Object values = synFields1.getValue();

   try {

       if (values instanceof JSONObject) {
           JSONObject jsonObject1 = new
             JSONObject(String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue()));
           String value = jsonObject1.getString("label");
           account_name.add(value);
       }
       else if (values instanceof String) {
           //here, you get a string

           //account_name.addAll(value);
           String value_names = String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue());
           String value_label = String.valueOf(synFields1.getLabel());
           // Log.e("account_name", 
           String.valueOf(account_name.add(value)));
           account_name.add(value_label );

           //account_name.add(value);
       }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Expected output: VS Hospital

Answer (score 0):

Make object using GSON 
here is tested code

```
Gson g = new Gson();
        String jsonString = "{\"name\": \"account_id\",  \"value\": {      \"value\": \"11x52925\",     \"label\":\"VSHospital\"  },\"label\":\"Account Name\",  \"uitype\": \"51\",  \"type\": {      \"defaultValue\": null  }}";
        Example p = g.fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
        Log.d("dsds",p.getValue().getLabel() );
```

Make POJO using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

add GSON in gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```